# CKEditor4 - How to prevent HTML comments from being stripped when switching from source to rich text editor

Tags: html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I switch from the source tab containing `<p>Hello <!--Comment I want to keep--></p>`
To the rich text editor, the comment is removed and I'm left with `Hello`

Digging through the CKEditor4 docs, I can't seem to find anyway to prevent the stripping of these comments.

Comment: Using 4.14.1 and this doesn't happen. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Wizard, I think I didn't explain the question well enough. I'm trying to persist the html comments from the source pain to the rich text editor. So, should be visible in both tabs but stripped when submitting the CKEditor changes. Odd request but that's the goal.